# Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am receiving this message when I tried starting my react native app. Usually this kind of format works on other multi screen navigation yet somehow does not work in this case.

Here is the error:

```
Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In 
react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly. More info: 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html
```

Here is my app format:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Login from './view/login.js'
import SignUp from './view/signup.js'

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Login
    },
    Signup: {
      screen: SignUp
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }

);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

Comment: it says you are missing app container

Comment: So basically I have to put everything in the Stack Navigator inside an App Container?  The thing I'm confused about is that this sort of setup has worked with my previous projects without any fault.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

React Navigation 3.0 has a number of [breaking changes](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/#breaking-changes) including an explicit app container required for the root navigator.

> In the past, any navigator could act as the navigation container at the top-level of your app because they were all wrapped in “navigation containers”. The navigation container, now known as an app container, is a higher-order-component that maintains the navigation state of your app and handles interacting with the outside world to turn linking events into navigation actions and so on.
>
> In v2 and earlier, the containers in React Navigation are
>   automatically provided by the create*Navigator functions. As of v3,
>   you are required to use the container directly. In v3 we also renamed
>   createNavigationContainer to createAppContainer.

Also please note that if you are now using v4, navigators have been moved to a separate repo. You'll now need to install and import from `'react-navigation-stack'`. For example `import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'` The solution below is for v3.

```
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({...});
const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

A more comprehensive code example:

```
import {
      createStackNavigator,
      createAppContainer
    } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './view/login.js'
import SignUp from './view/signup.js'

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: Login
    },
    Signup: {
      screen: SignUp
    }
  });

const App = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default App;
```

Comment: Super confused @Turnipdabeets are you able to provide a more comprehensive code example (I am new to React Native).

Comment: @Turnipdabeets I used this solution but I am getting an error "`createStackNavigator()` has been moved to `react-navigation-stack`. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator.html for more details." Can you please help me out.

Comment: @kb920 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817573/createstacknavigator-has-been-moved-to-react-navigation-stack

Comment: This works for me too. So basically you have to put everything inside an App Container.

Comment: How can I wrap this in a store then ?

Answer (score 26):

@Tom Dickson something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import ScreenOne from './ScreenOne';
import ScreenTwo from './ScreenTwo';

const NavStack = createStackNavigator({
    ScreenOne: { 
        screen: ScreenOne,
    },
    ScreenTwo: { 
        screen: ScreenTwo,
    },
});

const App = createAppContainer(NavStack);

export default App;
```

Then reference it with

```
<App />
```

Answer (score 11):

Create a new file ScreenContainer.js (you can choose the name).
Then in the ScreenContainer file add:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import MainScreen from './MainScreen'; 
import AboutScreen from './AboutScreen';

const NavigationStack = createStackNavigator({
    Main: { 
        screen: MainScreen,
    },
    About: { 
        screen: AboutScreen,
    },
});

const Container = createAppContainer(NavigationStack);

export default Container;
```

Then at your App.js file:

```
import Container from './ScreenContainer';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I wasted my 2.5 hours to got this solution after many google searches...Hope this will work.

**just import this two:**

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
```

**and make a little change to your code like this:**

*create const above the class*

```
const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

*and finally call that const in the class instead of `<RootStack/>`*

```
<AppNavigator />
```

Thankx!

Comment: It is because `createStackNavigator()` has been moved to `react-navigation-stack`. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import Login from './view/login.js'
import SignUp from './view/signup.js'

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Login
    },
    Signup: {
      screen: SignUp
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }

);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}

export default createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Friends: { screen: Friends },
});
```

**Simple i did**

```
const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default App;
```

**Instead of**

```
export default AppNavigator;
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './home';
import Details from './details';

const Root = createStackNavigator({

    home: { 

        screen: Home,
    },

    details: { 

        screen: Details,
    },

});

const container = createAppContainer(Root);
export default container;
```

in your App.js file reference it with `</container>`

Answer (score 2):

I had the code at the bottom

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <SimpleApp style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width }} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I simply replaced it with and it worked like a charm. Definitely, it's because updates in react-navigation library:

```
const App = createAppContainer(SimpleApp);
export default App;
```

Also, I included **createAppContainer** library into react-navigation at the top as well.

Answer (score 2):

This one is to create a bottom navigator with two tabs:

```
import {createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

export class Home extends Component{
   //...
}

export class Settings extends Component{
   //...
}     

const navig = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: Home,
  Settings: Settings
});

const App = createAppContainer(navig);

export default App;
```

Answer (score -2):

I been struggling from past  few days .Well might be you too been struggling to solve if and if you have deleted the react-navigation from package.json and installed using npm please check your backup project and see the navigation version and try to add the same and remove node-modules and do npm install.
Hope its works.

Good Luck breaking your head with React-Native :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This does not look like an answer.

Comment: Founder of Android!