# Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react native and I am trying to create an app with stack navigation. This is what I have on my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
// Import React Navigation
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'

// Import the screens
import Main from './components/Main';
import Chat from './components/Chat';



// Create the navigator
const navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Main: { screen: Main },
  Chat: { screen: Chat },
});
const App = createAppContainer(navigator)


export default navigator
```

This is also the error I am getting

```
Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly. More info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html

This error is located at:
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at registerRootComponent.js:17)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:16)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
- node_modules/@react-navigation/core/src/navigators/createNavigator.js:19:8 in getDerivedStateFromProps
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7663:46 in applyDerivedStateFromProps
- ... 20 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I am obviously doing something wrong, please assist

Comment: Did you read the information at that link? This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53367195/1531971

Comment: @Siraj thanks I got it fixed. I had to export "App" and corrected a <Text> error. thanks all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367195/invariant-violation-the-navigation-prop-is-missing-for-this-navigator)

Answer (score 4):

On the [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html#props-of-createappcontainer-on-react-native) of [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/en/)

> Note: In v2 and earlier, the containers in React Navigation are automatically provided by the create*Navigator functions. As of v3, you are required to use the container directly. In v3 we also renamed createNavigationContainer to createAppContainer.

That means, now you have to explicitly use the Container, which you have done in your code.

But you're still using (exporting) `navigator` not the `App`.

So, change your last line as

`export default App`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps :

1. Check your react-navigation version in package.json weather if its the latest 
   or the same one when you created the project initially .
2. If you have deleted the older one and used npm command then its have installed 
   react-native version latest one might be it not able to find the file in 
   library.
3. Finally delete the node-modules and check your older project and it's 
   react-navigation version and make it same in the current project inside
   package.json
4. Run npm install command

Run the project now .