# How to solve "Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator"?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I just updated the my react-navigation version from 1..0.0-beta.11 to latest react-navigation version 3. Now, in my project I have used the createStackNavigator in my HomeScreen.js. Here's the code for that-

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import {
  createStackNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
import WelcomeScreen from './WelcomeScreen';
import LoginScreen from './components/LoginScreen';
import NoteMeHome from './components/NoteMeHome';
import HomeDrawer from './HomeDrawer/HomeDrawer';
import SettingsScreen from './components/SettingsScreen';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  state = {
    getValue: null,
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    this.setState({ getValue: token });

  }

  render() {
    console.log('#ZZZ:', this.state.getValue);

    if(this.state.getValue !== null) {
      return (
        <AppStackNavigator/>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <AppStackNavigator2/>
      );
    }

  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  LoginScreen: {screen:LoginScreen},
  HomeDrawer: {screen:HomeDrawer},
  WelcomeScreen: {screen:WelcomeScreen},
  NoteMeHome: {screen:NoteMeHome},
  SettingsScreen: {screen:SettingsScreen}

}, 

{
  initialRouteName: 'WelcomeScreen'

}

)

const AppStackNavigator2 = createStackNavigator({
  WelcomeScreen: {screen:WelcomeScreen},
  HomeDrawer: {screen:HomeDrawer
  },

  LoginScreen: {screen:LoginScreen},
  NoteMeHome: {screen:NoteMeHome},

  SettingsScreen: {screen:SettingsScreen}

},  
{
  initialRouteName: 'WelcomeScreen'

}

)
export default HomeScreen;
```

Before making this update my code was running perfectly. But after updating it is showing the following error-

[image]

And here's the package.json file-

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-cardview": "^2.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

So, it would be very nice if anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: May be this existing threads can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379913/invariant-violation-the-navigation-prop-is-missing-for-this-navigator-in-react?noredirect=1&lq=1         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367195/invariant-violation-the-navigation-prop-is-missing-for-this-navigator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add this code in your question.You have to wrap your stack in **createAppContainer**.

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'



const AppStackNavigator = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
  LoginScreen: {screen:LoginScreen},
  HomeDrawer: {screen:HomeDrawer},
  WelcomeScreen: {screen:WelcomeScreen},
  NoteMeHome: {screen:NoteMeHome},
  SettingsScreen: {screen:SettingsScreen}

}, 
{
  initialRouteName: 'WelcomeScreen'

}
))


const AppStackNavigator2 = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
  WelcomeScreen: {screen:WelcomeScreen},
  HomeDrawer: {screen:HomeDrawer
  },

  LoginScreen: {screen:LoginScreen},
  NoteMeHome: {screen:NoteMeHome},

  SettingsScreen: {screen:SettingsScreen}

},  
{
  initialRouteName: 'WelcomeScreen'

}
))
```

Comment: After adding this, it is showing the following error-


**only one default export allowed per module.**

Comment: @S. M. Asif i have updated my answer.Just try this one.

Comment: @S.M.Asif in react-navigation 3.0 you have to wrap your container in AppContainer

Answer (score 1):

In react-navigation v3, you must wrap `makeRootNavigator` with `createAppContainer`.

Change your code to :

```
render() {
   const Navigator = createAppContainer(makeRootNavigator(this.state.accessToken));
   return <Navigator />
}
```

and don't forget to import `createAppContainer` on top of the file

```
import {createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
```

Answer (score 0):

In react-navigation v4, the structure of wrapping with `createAppContainer` remains but you must import `createAppContainer` from `react-navigation` and `createStackNavigator` from `react-navigation-stack`

for example

```
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import AnotherScreen from './AnotherScreen';

export default createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: HomeScreen,
      Another: AnotherScreen,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
    },
  ),
);
```