# Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run my app using latest react-navigation version but not working. Also trying using this solution ([Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367195/invariant-violation-the-navigation-prop-is-missing-for-this-navigator)) but no solution.

Error message

```
Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly. More info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html
```

My code

App.js

```
import App from './app/index';
export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { SignedOut } from "./router";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <SignedOut />;
  }
}
```

router.js

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

import SignUp from "./screens/SignUp";
import SignIn from "./screens/SignIn";

export const SignedOut = createStackNavigator({
  SignUp: {
    screen: SignUp,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Sign Up"
    }
  },
  SignIn: {
    screen: SignIn,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Sign In"
    }
  }
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/datomnurdin/auth-reactnative

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the previous versions of `react-navigation` the App containers were provided by the create*Navigation methods.

In `react-navigation` **v3** you need to add the App Container manually as mentioned [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html)

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

const SignedOutNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SignUp: {
    screen: SignUp,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Sign Up"
    }
  },
  SignIn: {
    screen: SignIn,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Sign In"
    }
  }
});

export const SignedOut = createAppContainer(SignedOutNavigator); // Use this
```

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer, but that link in the answer is dead. This the only article I could find gives an example of what the React code should look like when it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In react-navigation v3 you need to add the App Container manually as mentioned in below link
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html