# How can I render a different component based on a value from the Context API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

So I have this navigator component where depending on a value coming from another component, I need to show a different bottom navigation.

For now I am getting an error on the context consumer, here:

```
import { ThemeProvider, ThemeConsumer } from '../context/some';

const SelectedRoute = () => (
  <ThemeConsumer>
    {context => (context ? MainTabNavigator : PickupNavigator)}
  </ThemeConsumer>
);


export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      App: SelectedRoute,
    },
  ),
);
```

This is the only thing I have to create context:

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext(0);

export const ThemeProvider = ThemeContext.Provider;
export const ThemeConsumer = ThemeContext.Consumer;
```

I am getting this warning:

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

What can I do to render what I need correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You want to return JSX from the function given as child to `ThemeConsumer`, not just return a component.

```
const SelectedRoute = () => (
  <ThemeConsumer>
    {context => (context ? <MainTabNavigator /> : <PickupNavigator />)}
  </ThemeConsumer>
);
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error on the navigator >Yeah. But now I am getting an error regarding the navigation -> `Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly. More info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html`

damn it

Comment: @Reacting Yeah, [this might help with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367195/invariant-violation-the-navigation-prop-is-missing-for-this-navigator).

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is that I don't need `ThemeConsumer` actually, all I need is that value coming from `context`. Is there a way for me to access it without having to call `ThemeConsumer`?

Answer (score 0):

I have not run the example, but just suggesting from the docs. I thought the explanation was pretty clear but I could be wrong.

Just define a context variable in a separate file, in your case like this:

```
export const IndexContext = React.createContext({
    indexValue: value,
    toggleNavigator: () => {},
});
```

In your component(which receives indexValue), you can use the context value and toggle accordingly:

```
<ThemeContext.Consumer>
  {({indexValue, toggleNavigator}) => (
      // your component which uses the theme 
  )}
</ThemeContext.Consumer>
```

Since your component A is a stateful component, you can handle changes and update the context value there.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggleIndex = () => {
        this.setState({ index });
        this.handleStateIndexChange();
        MY_CONTEXT = index;
    };

    // State also contains the updater function so it will
    // be passed down into the context provider
    this.state = {
      index: index,
      toggleIndex: this.toggleIndex,
    };
  }

  render() {
    // The entire state is passed to the provider
    return (
      <IndexContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <Content />
      </IndexContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is that I don't need `ThemeConsumer` actually, all I need is that value coming from context. Is there a way for me to access it without having to call `ThemeConsumer`?