# How to change screens with react-navigation (using a button)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm new to react native, but I've been researching how to redirect to new activities with buttons for the last few hours with no avail. My current solution involves me using react-navigation from multiple files, with App.js creating the StackNavigator for the rest of the pages. However, whenever I press the button on Initial.js, nothing happens.

I followed Damien Manson's tutorial on [Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367195/invariant-violation-the-navigation-prop-is-missing-for-this-navigator), but the button still doesn't work. I tried referencing App before calling my button, but whenever I try to run it on the emulator, it doesn't show me an error log and it never loads. It stays at "Downloading JavaScript bundle: 100%" for minutes until the emulator itself crashes.

Here's my App.js

```
import Initial from './components/Initial'
import Statistics from './components/Statistics'

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Default: {
    screen: Initial
  },
  Stats: {
    screen: Statistics
  }
});

const App = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default App;
```

Here's my Initial.js

```
import { StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Font } from 'expo';

import App from '../App';

import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';
import Statistics from './Statistics';


export default class Initial extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {header: null} 

    componentDidMount() {
        Font.loadAsync({'pt': require('../assets/fonts/pt.ttf')});
        Font.loadAsync({'Karla': require('../assets/fonts/Karla-Regular.ttf')});
        Font.loadAsync({'Space-Mono': require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf')});
    }

    state = { fontLoaded: false};

    async componentDidMount() {
        await Font.loadAsync({'pt': require('../assets/fonts/pt.ttf'),});
        await Font.loadAsync({'Karla': require('../assets/fonts/Karla-Regular.ttf'),});
        await Font.loadAsync({'Space-Mono': require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),});
        this.setState({fontLoaded: true});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground
                source = {require('../assets/blue-bin.jpg')}
                style = {styles.container}>
                <View style = {styles.parentView}>
                    {this.state.fontLoaded ? (<Text style={styles.logoText}>!arbitrary</Text>) : null}
                    <Image source = {require('../assets/sadparrot.gif')} style = {styles.logo}/>
                    <Text style = {styles.textBox}>With its easily navigatible interface, the Chicago-based app, !arbitrary, aims to educate the masses about recyclable items, while emphasizing the importance of being sustainable.</Text>
                    <View style = {styles.redirect}>
                        <Button
                            title="Start"
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Statistics')}
                         /> 
                    </View>    
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
    },
    parentView: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(5,9,12, 0.6)',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
    logoText: {
      color: '#fff',
      fontSize: 36,
      fontFamily: 'pt'
    },
    textBox: {
      width: 200,
      height: 175,
      fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
      fontSize: 14,
      color: '#fff',
      borderColor: '#fff',
      borderWidth: 2,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      marginTop: 50,
      padding: 20
    },
    logo: {
      width: 200,
      height: 200
    },
    redirect: {
      width: 80,
      height: 30,
      marginTop: 30
    },
    statistics: {
      flex: 1,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      backgroundColor: '#1B384F'
    },
    bigText: {
      color: '#fff',
      fontSize: 20,
      fontFamily: 'Space-Mono'
    }
});
```

Here's my Statistics.js

```
import { StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Font } from 'expo';
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';

class Statistics extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Text>Avail!</Text>
        );
    }
}
export default withNavigation(Statistics);
```

NOTE: I omitted my StyleSheet in Initial.js for the sake of being concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to navigate to your screen name which is `Stats`.

```
<Button
 title="Start"
 onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Stats')}/>
```

Comment: because you were navigating to a route that doesn't exists, your routes names are `Stats` and `Default`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed is by using `withNavigation`

In **Statistics** class,

1st, Import `withNavigation`.

`import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';`

Then, export **Statistics** class as below.

`export default withNavigation(Statistics)`

Comment: I added my Statistics.js in my initial question with your suggestion. The app doesn't run at all now and instead portrays the error (or warning?) `Require cycle: App.js -> components\Initial.js -> App.js`

Comment: Can you also add those two statements to the `Initial` class?

Comment: Just added them, but now the default screen is Statistics.js. Wouldn't I need to do `export default Initial extends React.Component` instead?

Comment: Yes, please. Change it back to `export default Initial extends React.Component`. This is strange. I fixed the same problem with the above method(solution).

Comment: `Require cycle: App.js -> components\Initial.js -> App.js` This is just a warning. Am I right? Did you try Dismissing it?

Comment: Yes, I changed it back and Initial.js is the default screen now, however, the button still doesn't work.

Comment: @Letta there's no need to use `withNavigation`, your route name is `Stats` but you want to navigate to `Statistics` which does exists in the `RootStack`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Default: {
    screen: Initial
  },
  Stats: {
    screen: props => <Statistics {...props} />
  }
});
```