# Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. error on expo

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

My problem is the same with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367195/invariant-violation-the-navigation-prop-is-missing-for-this-navigator) but I have difficulty what should I do if I'm using store provider like this:

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
   {
      Loading: MainLoadingScreen,
      App: MainNavigator,
      Auth: AuthStack,
      Signup: SignupStack
   },
   {
      initialRouteName: 'Loading',
   }
);



const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I'm getting this error:
Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly. More info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html

This error is located at:

```
    in Navigator (at App.js:114)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at App.js:113)
    in Provider (at App.js:112)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
- node_modules\@react-navigation\core\lib\module\navigators\createNavigator.js:1:1637 in getDerivedStateFromProps
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:6896:46 in applyDerivedStateFromProps
- ... 20 more stack frames from framework internals
```

How do I convert my code so I can use the format shown here? :

> const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your switch navigator with `createAppContainer`:

```js
const MainSwitch = createSwitchNavigator(
   {
      Loading: MainLoadingScreen,
      App: MainNavigator,
      Auth: AuthStack,
      Signup: SignupStack
   },
   {
      initialRouteName: 'Loading',
   }
);

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(MainSwitch)

export default App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function and assign it to the value of `Const`.

```js
const App = function Appfunc() {
  return (
     <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

```js
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)

export default AppContainer
```

Comment: But it's an arrow function already. How do I combine it with assigning the switchnavigator to createAppContainer?

Comment: It's right to do it like your question. Look at my answer. The arrow function may not function properly. Try my answer.