# `createStackNavigator()` has been moved to `react-navigation-stack`

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-navigation in my project, and this error pops up.

I googled this error message and found no result.

(I can't post images yet)

The error message reads:

```
`createStackNavigator()` has been moved to `react-navigation-stack`. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator.html for more details.
```

The code worked on my friend's machine, somehow

Answer (score 89):

As said by the error, in `react-navigation` version 4, all navigators have been moved to separate repos so you have to install them separately.

For the `StackNavigator` you have to install `react-navigation-stack` using:

```
npm i react-navigation-stack   //or yarn add react-navigation-stack
```

after that, go to the file where you define `createStackNavigator` and change:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
```

to:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
```

This error may happen because your friend used react-navigation v. 3 but in your `package.json` it's using a `react-navigation` version >3. When you did `npm install` it downloaded the latest version of react-navigation (that updated last week to version 4 with those changes)

The same  goes for the other navigators.

SOURCE: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

Comment: Or using Yarn: yarn add react-navigation-stack

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but you should mention first about install react-navigation-stack.

Answer (score 26):

> Install **`react-navigation-stack`** NPM package in version 4 and it will solve the issue.

For the StackNavigator you have to install react-navigation-stack using:

```
npm install react-navigation-stack --save
```

Check https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html for more details

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Answer (score 11):

> Step 1: Install `react-navigation-stack` by `npm i react-navigation-stack`
>
> Step 2: Moved `createStackNavigator` to newly created package

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
-----
```

Additionally:

> `createBottomTabNavigator`also moved to `react-navigation-tabs` from
> `react-navigation`

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator} from "react-navigation-tabs";
```

Answer (score 9):

1. `npm install react-navigation-stack`
2. `npm install react-navigation`
3. `expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated`
4. [Use app container](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html)

Example

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({ /* your routes here */ });
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

// Now AppContainer is the main component for React to render
export default AppContainer;
```

Answer (score 5):

firstly: install

```
npm install react-navigation-stack
```

secondly: import react-navigation-stack

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

Answer (score 4):

you have to follow two steps:

1. `yarn add react-navigation-stack` **OR** `npm install react-navigation-stack`
2. `import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";`

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2):

Now the dependency is change new react-native version 0.61

```
// old one
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'; it's changed

// latest one 
first of all insatll the dependency 

npm install react-navigation-stack

import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';  //this

export default createStackNavigator(
  {
   .....
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `npm install @react-navigation/stack` or `yarn add @react-navigation/stack` in the command prompt and import it like `import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'`. I hope this would work fine. For more info, [read here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/).

Answer (score 1):

Change (Mude)

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

To (Para)

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

Answer (score 1):

use single line command below to install dependencies

```
npx expo-cli install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-navigation-stack
```

and change import statement as below

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this same error using installing these.

1. npm install react-navigation
2. npm i react-navigation-stack
3. npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view

and i fallow this

https://medium.com/better-programming/react-native-navigating-between-the-screens-and-code-structure-for-beginners-6b815ee8f79