# Error: `createNavigationContainer()` has been removed. Use `createAppContainer()` instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

As you can see in my simple code, i am not using createNavigationContainer/createAppContainer but i am getting that error. I do not know why this is happening. I am stuck !

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Router, Stack, Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';

import LogIn from './pages/LogIn';
import SignUp from './pages/SignUp';
import { View } from 'react-native';


export default class Routes extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <Stack key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
                    <Scene key="LogIn" component={LogIn} title="Login" initial={true}/>
                    <Scene key="SignUp" component={SignUp} title="SignUp"/>
                </Stack>

            </Router>

        );
    }
}
```

[image]>

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.2.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-screens": "~1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817573/createstacknavigator-has-been-moved-to-react-navigation-stack/57822066#57822066

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to see if it work for you

```
npm i react-navigation-stack --save
```

Also try to upgrade your package if this is not work

Ref [link](https://medium.com/fantageek/using-react-navigation-3-0-in-react-native-apps-38cd5020fbbe)

Answer (score 0):

Read this IMPORTANT NOTES carefully, and change versions on package.json like this

```
"react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
"react-native-router-flux": "4.2.0-beta.1",
```

**IMPORTANT NOTES**

v4.2.0-beta.x is based on React Navigation v4.x

v4.1.0-beta.x is based on React Navigation v3.x

v4.0.x is based on [React Navigation v2.x].

See this branch and docs for v3 based on deprecated React Native Experimental Navigation API. It is not supported and may not work with latest React Native versions.
v4.0.0-beta.x is based on React Navigation v1.5.x. See this branch for this version. It is also not supported and may not work with the latest React Native versions.