# Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. in react-navigation 4

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to create a navigation drawer for my React native App, using 2 screens,home screen and connection sreen but i keep getting this error:

```
Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In 
react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly. More info: 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html
```

what's wrong with my code please.
my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Search from './Components/Search'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer'
import { createStackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
//import  Connection from './Screens/ConnectionScreen';
import  AccueilScreen from './Screens/AccueilScreen';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <AppDrawerNavigator/>
        );
  }

}

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  //Se_Connecter: Connection,
  Accueil:{ 
    screen : AccueilScreen,
  },
});
const AppNavigator= createAppContainer(AppDrawerNavigator);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367195/invariant-violation-the-navigation-prop-is-missing-for-this-navigator)

Answer (score 2):

You are rendering the `DrawerNavigator` without using the AppContainer (that you created)

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <AppNavigator/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot i didn't pay attention to that detail. the problem is no longer there